# if value that i want to find is in object in array, i want to return true by javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

if value that i want to find is in object in array, i want to return true by javascript

below is array data.

```
[
  {
    holdings: [
      { product: { id: 1, prodName: 'LX세미콘', prodCode: '108320' } },
      { product: { id: 2, prodName: '컴투스', prodCode: '078340' } }
    ]
  },
  {
    holdings: [ { product: { id: 1, prodName: 'LX세미콘', prodCode: '108320' } } ]
  }
]
```

if any prodCode of product in holdings is "108320", i want to return true.

i tried

Comment: what did you do so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const data = [
  {
    holdings: [
      { product: { id: 1, prodName: 'LX세미콘', prodCode: '108320' } },
      { product: { id: 2, prodName: '컴투스', prodCode: '078340' } }
    ]
  },
  {
    holdings: [ { product: { id: 1, prodName: 'LX세미콘', prodCode: '108320' } } ]
  }
]


function present(code, data) {
  return data.some(item =>
    item.holdings.some(holding =>
      holding.product.prodCode === code
    )
  )
}

console.log(present('108320', data));
```